# How to align the divs vertically with css?

Tags: html, css

- I would like for the divs to all be on one line. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?*
  `

  .main{
        width: 20vw;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .border1{
        margin-left: auto;
        height: 5px;
        width: 33%;
        background-color:
        #f5c70a;

  }
  .border2{
  margin: auto;
  height: 5px;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: #66ABC7;
  }
  .border3{
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 33%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #5a0a60;
  }
  `
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzIza.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

CSS:

```
.parent {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
// ... element will be centered vertically here
</div>
```